# Reuse some functionalities contain with salesforce.com platform's Sales application

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

I am ding some customisation for salesforce.com platform Sales application. For one of tab that I have newly created, I want to re use functionality implemented on 'Opportunity' page's, 'Products (Price Book Name)' list box (with those related functionalities - select price book and make Opportunity Product).

Comment: I've not tried this but using an <apex:related> might do the trick for the products, depends if it adds the extra buttons or not though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you need to recreate this functionality yourself. Though Lacey is right that you can leverage `<apex:relatedList>` for related lists, you will not be able to extract *all* the functionality from Opportunity Products, line items, price book, etc., without coding this yourself - by hand :(

Sorry for the bad news!